# Can't recognize data variable. Uncaught ReferenceError: edu_id is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm about to pass the edu_id from ajax to my controller using Laravel

**anchor tag**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showEditEducation(some_specific_id);" title=""><i class="la la-pencil"></i></a>
```

**Javascript function**

```
function showEditEducation($edu_id)
{
    console.log($edu_id);
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ route('show-edit-education', $user->id) }}",
        data: {"education_id": edu_id,"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            $("#showMe").html(json.html);
        }
     });
}
```

**Laravel Controller**

```
 public function showEditEducationForm(Request $request, $user_id)
    {
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        $education_id = $request->input('education_id'); 

        $applicantEducation = ApplicantEducation::find($education_id);

        dd($applicantEducation);

    }
```

The console.log output is alright. It returns a number. The only problem is that ajax doesn't recognize "edu_id"

Comment: what's the difference between `$edu_id` and `edu_id` ?

Comment: your edit does not change the fact that `edu_id` is most likely `undefined` - is there a reason you are not using the defined variable: `$edu_id`?

Comment: WOW!! THanks man. I'm so stupid by not recognizing that easily

Comment: It works now. I'm following someone's ajax code. I wonder why their code works even though they are not putting the dollar sign. hmmm

Comment: Yeah, cut-n-paste rarely is worth it. The reason _that other person's_ page works is because they likely have a global JS variable named `edu_id` and they are getting lucky with their poor design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what Sir Randy says. Just simply putting a dollar sign will solve the problem.

```
edu_id
```

to

```
$edu_id
```

**Final javascript function code**

```
function showEditEducation($edu_id)
{
    console.log($edu_id);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ route('show-edit-education', $user->id) }}",
        data: {"education_id": $edu_id,"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            $("#showMe").html(json.html);
        }
 });
```

}